# TreeView (TreeItem) - get hierarchy index possible?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have a TreeView that looks like this:

```
-Parent1
- - Child1
- - Child2
- - - Subchild1
-Parent2
- - Child99
```

Is there a method or a simple way to get the hierarchical index of a `TreeItem` in the tree?

For example:

**Parent1** would have a hierarchical **index of 0**.

**Child1** would have a hierarchical **index of 1**.

**Subchild1** would have a hierarchical **index of 2**.

**Parent2** would have a hierarchical **index of 0**.

**Child99** would have a hierarchical **index of 1**.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that gets on mind is using Java Reflect API, getSuperclass() method, as Java doc says: http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/reflect/class/getSuperclass.html

Please see the following Example:

```
public class Subclass{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map = new HashMap();
        Map map2 = new HashMap();
        printSuperclasses(map);
        printSuperclasses(map2);
}

    static void printSuperclasses(Object o) {
        Class subclass = o.getClass();
        Class superclass = subclass.getSuperclass();
        int i=0;
        while (superclass != null) {
           String className = superclass.getName();
           i++;
           System.out.println(className+" "+i);
           subclass = superclass;
           superclass = subclass.getSuperclass();
        }
     }
}
```

The output provided by this example is:

java.util.AbstractMap 1

java.lang.Object 2

java.util.AbstractMap 1

java.lang.Object 2

*That means that in hierarchy the parent of Map object is AbstractMap(index 1), and the parent of AbstractMap is Object (index 2).*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't have anything to do with TreeView. It's about classes and inheritance.